adjective as a noun
I misheard querida as carita (diminutive of the adjective cara), which got me wondering…

Are adjectives productively used as nouns, either as-are or by adding -ita or the like?

And if so, then is carita, specifically, a valid such construction?


Alternatively, can an adjective have the diminutive -ita added (and remain an adjective)?

And if so, then is carita, specifically, a valid such construction?



(I'm asking colloquially, not according to the RAE.)

In Spanish, adjectives referring to some personal or physical trait can indeed be used as vocatives (vocatives are nouns used to call or to speak to somebody). So the answer to the question as to whether adjectives can be productively used as nouns in that context, either in their original form or by adding some diminutive or augmentative suffix, is affirmative:

Hola, linda / bonita, ¿cómo estás?

Flaco, ¿me das una mano?

Grandote / Grandulón, no te metas con los más pequeños.

Fortachón, peléate con los de tu tamaño.

Chiquita, eres un ángel.

Gordito, deberías comer más sano.

Genio, ¿me ayudas a resolver este problema?

Tontito, deja de hacerte el vivo.



Many thanks! [15 characters]

Me gusta fortachón. jaja

I'm not sure about what you're asking exactly. Also you have chosen a difficult word to talk about because cara can be a noun, meaning "face", and also an adjective, meaning "expensive". As adjective, it also can mean "dear" or "beloved" (querida) but such use is not extended, it's considered a cultism.
Both of them have the diminutive "carita". The presence of that suffix does not change the nature of the word, it remains a noun or an adjective.
Here in Málaga, Spain, we prefer the use of -illa instead of -ita for the diminutives. In these streets you can hear

Alegra esa carilla, muchacha. [Put a smile in your face, girl] [noun]
Esa camisa es bastante carilla, ¿no? [That shirt is pretty expensive, isn't it?] [adjective]

On the other hand, in the related links column you can find an interesting question/answer on how you can create nouns from an adjectives using suffixes.

Thank you!  This tells me that, yes, adjectives can have -ita added.  My other question was whether adjectives can be used as nouns; but the answer you link to (and Wikipedia) tell me they can: Tenemos que tirar las estropeadas.  Am I correct in guessing, then, that one can address his darling as carita?

@msh210 I think that it's not common. "Cara mía" sounds Italian for "My dear". For me "carita" in your context sounds like calling someone "little face".

Using "caro/cara" for "dear" or "beloved" is not so strange, especially when you say "mi carísima esposa" ("my beloved/expensive wife").

@aerobiomat Using just "carita" to address someone is common?

Never heard that.

Creo que deberías retroceder un paso más y preguntar directamente si

Are adjectives productively used as nouns, either as-are or by adding -ita or the like?

A lo cual la respuesta es que obviamente sí. Si yo digo algo como:

Los tramposos arruinan el juego.

Qué viene a ser ‘tramposo’? Yo diría que ambas cosas. El término mienta a una persona que a su vez tiene la propiedad de ser tramposa.
En cuanto al proceso inverso, el de convertir un sustantivo en adjetivo, es más difícil. Aunque coloquialmente escucho algunas frases con las que podría argumentar que sí se puede, dudo que sea considerado ‘estándar’. Así que quedate con lo primero de todo: Los adjetivos seguro que también pueden hacer de sustantivo.
Después:

Alternatively, can an adjective have the diminutive -ita added (and remain an adjective)?

Sí, por supuesto. Las reglas para las deformaciones de las palabras se tratan prácticamente igual en sustantivos y en adjetivos. Un ejemplo claro que lo demuestra es que la RAE menciona las reglas para formar plurales sólo en base a cómo termina la palabra, sin hacer más distinción en cuanto a si es adjetivo o sustantivo. Se consideran iguales.
Por lo tanto, yo puedo decir:

Los trampositos arruinan el juego.

O ‘tramposillos’, ‘tramposuchos’, etc. vas a tener que ver cuál sufijo queda mejor. Pero sí, los sufijos diminutivos valen tanto para sustantivos como adjetivos.
Sabiendo todo esto, mi conclusión es que yo creo que lo que escuchaste no fue el diminutivo del adjetivo caro/a, sino el diminutivo del sustantivo cara, que sería más verosímil como fórmula de tratamiento equivalente a ‘querido/a’, tal como lo muestra el siguiente ejemplo (Serrat - Romance de Curro):

Mil veces le pide
Y mil veces que "nones"
De compartir sueños
Cama y macarrones
Le dice burlona:
"Carita gitana
Cómo hacer buen vino
De una cepa enana"

Claramente ‘carita gitana’ es el vocativo que usa.

Thank you! [15 characters]

Qué el diminutivo de "cara" como nombre significa querido?? ¿Eso desde cuando es? En el texto de Serrat significa con cara de gitana! Burlona y con carita de gitana. No significa querida.

@RubioRic Ella es quien le dice de forma burlona a él ‘carita gitana’. No entiendo cuál es tu punto. Explica mejor.

Carita no es equivalente a querido en ese contexto. Vamos, que tu ejemplo no es válido.

"Sabiendo todo esto, mi conclusión es que yo creo que lo que escuchaste no fue el diminutivo del adjetivo caro/a, sino el diminutivo del sustantivo cara, que sería más verosímil como fórmula de tratamiento equivalente a ‘querido/a’, tal como lo muestra el siguiente ejemplo" Todo esto entre comillas es falso. "Carita gitana" no es equivalente a "Querida gitana". Mejor ahora? Más claro?

@RubioRic De nuevo, es ella a él quien se lo dice. Sería equivalente a ‘querido gitano’, porque ambos son vocativos, son fórmulas de tratamiento. Te recomiendo que vayas a escuchar la canción primero, que se nota que no tenés idea sobre lo que trata y después vengas a criticar. Mejor ahora? Más claro?

@tac Cada vez va a peor, ahora "carita gitana" es equivalente a "querido gitano". Un cambio de sexo mágico. Me da igual quien se lo diga a quien, lo que dice es que tiene cara de gitano/a: ojos negros, piel morena ... Puedo escuchar la canción mil veces que querido no aparece ahí. Carita de ángel, carita gitana, ... no son "fórmulas de tratamiento"
